# Initialization of HLS livestream on iOS, subsequent loads are successful

Tags: ios, safari, http-live-streaming

I have a livestream video I'm trying to implement with HLS, on other platforms I'm using Hls.js but iOS has native support so I'm using a normal video element for it on iOS. However, when I start the livestream, the video player chokes and returns a media error with error code 3 which is a decoding error.

However if I refresh the page it'll load the livestream ok. It seems to be erroring out when it encounters the first few requests of a new livestream. Has anyone encountered something like this before? Any tips for how to debug further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone ever has this issue and needs a work-around. I was able to "fix" this by adding error handling if the stream was running in iOS.

If it failed on the initial load, I'd just try loading it again. It'd work on the second load. I'm still not sure why it's failing the first time, but at least it's working now.